# stm2cubeide - Access denied

Tags: stm32, stm32cubeide

I use stm2cubeide software for a course in my studies.
I opened a new folder in the `c:\users` and installed stm2cubeide and a first program that I tried to run. When I try to build that project it shows the following error:

```
Errors occurred during the build.
Errors running builder 'CDT Builder' on project 'blinky'.
Cannot create file, access denied: C:\Users\Eitan\blinky\Debug.
C:\Users\Eitan\blinky\Debug
Cannot create file, access denied: C:\Users\Eitan\blinky\Debug.
C:\Users\Eitan\blinky\Debug
```

Can I fix this problem without moving all the packages to another folder?

**Soultion:**
I changed the permissions of the folder that contain the specific folder that contain the project. and then the build worked.

Comment: Eclipse based IDEs expect you to assign a folder as the *workspace* folder and they expect project folders to reside in that folder. In your case, the project folder resides in your own user home directory. Maybe Eclipse doesn't like it...

Comment: Ok, could be, what can i do to change that? let him to create an enviorment and copy my project in the default folder he created?

Comment: Yes, I would try that. But after you move your project folder to a new workspace folder, you will probably need to import in using IDE using File->Import... This is a seamless step and works with default settings. You just need to choose the project folder which will already be in the workspace folder.

Comment: Try to open a File Explorer and navigate to the folder `C:\Users\Eitan\blinky`. Try to make a new folder and remove it. Reason: sometimes folders are not created with correct permissions, and just navigating to them in File Explorer may reveal or even fix it. Creating a folder manually will let you know if there is a permissions problem. Let us know if this gives you some new information.

Comment: Now its work. thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should try running stm2cubeide as administrator.

Comment: Checked, i already run it as administrator. but thanks anyway